# What paths should I ignore when checking a SharePoint project into Subversion?

Tags: source-control

I'm looking at adding a handful of SharePoint projects from a third-party to our source control system, Subversion. However, I'm not exactly sure what ignore patterns should be setup.

Right away a */pkgobj/Release/* directory jumped to my attention, and [this thread on Microsoft's boards](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/4cf8a27a-0ad9-454e-90d0-a7c347b658b0/) suggests */pkg/* as well.

So that I don't miss any others, what patterns should I be adding to TortoiseSVN/my source control client of choice so that I don't include unnecessary files when I make these commits?

Current TortoiseSVN global ignore pattern:

`*.o *.lo *.la *.al .libs *.so *.so.[0-9]* *.a *.pyc *.pyo *.rej *~ #*# .#* .*.swp .DS_Store bin obj Thumbs.db *.suo *.user *.webinfo *.Publish.xml *.Publish *.cache StyleCop.Cache pkg pkgobj`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would also exclude /bin and /obj.  We use Team Foundation Services and these two plus the two you mentioned are the only ones excluded.

Comment: +1 I should have included my existing ignore pattern in my original question.

Answer (score 5):

I also exclude the Solution User Options files (.suo) as they change with navigating the projects on every machine.

Comment: AS Jim mentioned definitely exclude the .suo file as well as the pkg and pkgobj directories.